# How do I get more decimal in clf.predict_proba(X_test)?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a pandas dataframe, for a binary classification case (category A, and category B). To get  `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test` I do 70:30 split like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
target = pd.DataFrame(data['good'])
features = data.drop('good', axis=1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, 
                                                    target, 
                                                    test_size = 0.3, 
                                                    random_state = 0)
```

Then I did RandomForest classifier, with that this code

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=2, random_state=0)
model = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

As usual you can do get the prediction by doing `clf.predict(X_test)`. It give `numpy.ndarray` object like this

```
array(['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1'], dtype=object)
```

Then, I want to calculate prediction probabiblity by `clf.predict_proba(X_test)` and the result is

```
array([[ 0.7  ,  0.3  ],
       [ 0.8  ,  0.2  ],
       [ 0.4  ,  0.6  ],
       [ 0.8  ,  0.2  ],
       [ 0.5  ,  0.5  ],
       [ 0.1  ,  0.9  ],
       [ 0.5  ,  0.5  ],
       [ 0.3  ,  0.7  ],
       [ 0.3  ,  0.7  ],
       [ 0.5  ,  0.5  ]])
```

I want to get more decimal in `clf.predict_proba(X_test)` output. (I am expected 3 decimals) For example,

```
array([[ 0.712  ,  0.288  ],
       [ 0.845  ,  0.155  ... etc
```

It would be better if the answer also convert and merge `clf.predict(X_test)` and `clf.predict_proba(X_test)` to pandas dataframe as well, because I would continue to calculate GINI index. Thanks in advance

Comment: `np.set_printoptions(precision=3)`?

Comment: @Divakar works, can you make it to pandas dataframe

Comment: Just append the results to the dataframe using column names. Something like `data['prob_0']=output[:,0]` and `data['prob_1']=output[:,1]`, where `output = clf.predict_proba(X_test)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the 'n_estimators' in the model parameters (seems like you have set it to default 10).